# Does anybody have experience with highfrequency R package?

Tags: r

For the life of it I can't get this package to work with my own data. Is it essential to use the `convert` and `TAQload` to use your own data with this package? I would like to get in touch with someone that got experience with this and got it working. I have sent e-mails to both authors but no reply so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use the convert code in case you have a premeditated setup that provides data into .xts files. Kris Boudt et al (n.d) quote "highfrequency provides functionality to convert raw data from several data providers into xts objects".

Check also [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326286/convert-csv-file-for-further-manipulation-using-highfrequency-package-on-r) for further reference.

Bibliography:
Boudt, K., Cornelissen, J. and Payseur, S. (no date) Highfrequency: Toolkit for the analysis of highfrequency financial data in R. Available at: https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/highfrequency/inst/doc/highfrequency.pdf?revision=37&root=highfrequency&pathrev=38 (Accessed: 14 July 2016).

Comment: Cheers for your answer. I have pulled a lot of hair over this packages and there are a lot of flaws in my opinion, but I guess you can sometimes only expect that someone build a package for they own data/use.. Anyhow, I got it working in the end.

Comment: Ye I know,  also tried to contact the authors two separate times with no success. The examples have to be enriched especially for the convert function as i struggled a lot. These examples to my understanding assume a certain level of familiarity with statistical programming with R. But you can't complain, these guys devoted so many hours to create something that everybody can use for free.