# highfrequency package (R) issue with timezone in stock quotes data clean-up

Tags: r, timestamp, timezone

This to me looks very suspicious I have debugged through it and I am still not sure it is a bug or not.

I have prepared sample data to replicate this issue, the file is not small (25MB, real-life quotes data for a typical trading day). The download [link](https://transfer.pcloud.com/download.html?code=5ZbH8QVZ6qDFjMDsUrpZsMlUZGOx0lXruwEyqHdyVgM2wWjSe2JSy) is here and passcode is 654321. I believe a day's worth of quotes data is necessary for this problem in case you think it's too much.

```
# My system locale in R is this (Europe/London).
# My system time is `BST`.
# The sample quotes data is in timezone `US/Eastern`;
# this implies that the market hours in data file conforms
# to actual US market hours (9:30-16:00), and not adjusted to
# whatever my system timezone is. 
# In my case it would've been 13:30-20:00.
# I'm running R-4.2.1 on Debian 10 based Linux.

> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"


# helper function to read quotes data in a `highfrequency` conforming format.

read.quotes <- function(path){
  quotes.data <- readr::read_csv(path,
                                 show_col_types = F, 
                                 col_types = vroom::cols(ask_size="i",
                                                         bid_size="i",
                                                         conditions="c"),
                                 locale = readr::locale(tz = "US/Eastern"))

  colnames(quotes.data) <- c("DateTime", 
                             "Symbol", 
                             "AskEx", 
                             "AskPrice", 
                             "AskSize", 
                             "BidEx", 
                             "BidPrice",
                             "BidSize",
                             "Conditions",
                             "Tape")
  
  quotes.data <- quotes.data %>% 
                 dplyr::select(DateTime, 
                               BidEx, 
                               BidPrice, 
                               BidSize,
                               AskPrice, 
                               AskSize, 
                               Symbol) %>%
                 dplyr::rename(DT=DateTime, 
                               EX=BidEx, 
                               BID=BidPrice, 
                               BIDSIZ=BidSize, 
                               OFR=AskPrice, 
                               OFRSIZ=AskSize, 
                               SYMBOL=Symbol) %>%
                 data.table::as.data.table
  
  data.table::setkeyv(quotes.data, c("SYMBOL", "DT"))
  
  quotes.data
}

# This function shall give us a data object that's the same as the package's `sampleQDataRaw`. 
# The package's sample data is artificial, therefore in nature these two data objects are not comparable; 
# Creating the correct object is essential.

# We should expect same output for data types with following statements.
> qdata <- read.quotes(path_to_the_file_on_your_computer)
> str(highfrequency::sampleQDataRaw)
> str(qdata)

# Observe that the qData ends at 11:59, not 15:59 or 16:00
# which is the correct US market close time, 
# in timezones like `EDT`, `US/Eastern`, or `America/New York`.

> highfrequency::quotesCleanup(qDataRaw=qdata)
# output 
[1] "The  NYSE is the exchange with the highest volume."
$qData
                            DT SYMBOL    BID    OFR OFRSIZ BIDSIZ EX MIDQUOTE
    1: 2022-05-02 09:30:00.951     GS 305.49 306.00      1      1  N  305.745
    2: 2022-05-02 09:30:01.031     GS 305.49 305.99      1      1  N  305.740
    3: 2022-05-02 09:30:01.031     GS 305.49 306.00      1      1  N  305.745
    4: 2022-05-02 09:30:01.031     GS 305.49 305.99      1      1  N  305.740
    5: 2022-05-02 09:30:01.031     GS 305.49 305.98      1      1  N  305.735
   ---                                                                       
82457: 2022-05-02 11:59:59.758     GS 308.63 308.84      1      2  N  308.735
82458: 2022-05-02 11:59:59.767     GS 308.63 308.84      1      1  N  308.735
82459: 2022-05-02 11:59:59.827     GS 308.63 308.84      1      2  N  308.735
82460: 2022-05-02 11:59:59.827     GS 308.63 308.84      1      3  N  308.735
82461: 2022-05-02 11:59:59.997     GS 308.63 308.84      1      3  N  308.735

$report
         initialObservations        removedFromZeroQuotes  removedOutsideExchangeHours removedFromSelectingExchange 
                      413547                            1                       224780                       106255 
   removedFromNegativeSpread       removedFromLargeSpread    removedFromMergeTimestamp              removedOutliers 
                           2                            0                           48                            0 
           finalObservations 
                       82461
```

Someone running a system in US locale (or physically based in US/Eastern) loads up my data and fires away with this clean-up process, if she/he gets the correct output it would indicate `quotesCleanup` does not correctly respect the timezone other than US (given it's US stock market).

If the US person does get the same result as I did here, then `quotesCleanup` might have different issue then.

Unless, it is that my data is malformed and this is indeed what I failed to diagnose so far (I don't believe it is the case, not that I didn't try).

Internally `highfrequency` has a function called `exchangeHoursOnly` to extract rows that fall between market open and close time; it converts `POSIXct` to `numeric` with `tz` information, but it seems `as.numeric` did not respect `tz` info. It's not very clear to see from their code, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok I can now confirm that there's incorrect usage of `as.numeric` and `timeDate::format` in `highfrequency`; their whole clean-up and aggregation routines become unstable because of this bug. I'll write an answer shortly discussing the details. I'll also raise it to the team as well.